# Cannot find where this colorscheme setting is being set for vim on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, unix, vim, vimrc

A long time ago I was farting around with color schemes for vim and I remember setting a line somewhere `colorscheme sonofobsidian`. I did this before I knew what I was doing with vim, unix, OS X, etc. Now when I do `:so $MYVIMRC` which reloads my vimrc file I see a little message at the bottom saying it cannot load color scheme `sonofobsidian`. I'm pretty positive I did this long ago but I have NO IDEA where this setting is coming from. It's most definitely not in `~/.vimrc`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not caused by something I did previously. Rather, the name of the color scheme file MUST match the name the color scheme specifies within the file. For example:

You cannot have:

```
// sons-of-obsidian.vim
...
...
let g:colors_name="sonofobsidian"
...
...
```

Whatever `colors_name` is set to must match the name of the file. I renamed this color scheme file because the real name is supposed to be "sons of obsidian". Simply modifying the file so that variable matched my new name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try grepping for 'sonofobsidian' in `~/.vimrc`, `~/.gvimrc`, and the entire `~/.vim` directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

If `vundle` is using for your vim plugins, you should check if there any lines was comment which looks like:

```
" Bundle 'Son-of-Obisidian'
```

Then, uncomment it. The color will back again.

Else, please go to vim `colors` folder. normally, it will be found at: `~/.vim/colors` in Linux or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\colors` in Windows. Check if there any file looks like:

```
sonofobsidian.vim
```

If it cannot be found, download the file from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3260 and copy the `sonofobsidian.vim` to `colors` folder. And everything will be fine.

Comment: I appreciate it but as you can see above I did find the answer already. Though this may help future Googlers :)

Comment: Okay. After check the source code of `sonofobsidian.vim`. That's because this color file missing terminal color. It only for Gui

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not the issue. I'm using it in a GUI. I already fixed the issue. It was that the variable in the color scheme file didn't match the file name. When VIM tries to reload the set colorscheme later it uses the value in the variable to retrieve it. When it doesn't match the file name it can't find the colorscheme. [See my answer before yours](http://superuser.com/questions/685095/cannot-find-where-this-colorscheme-setting-is-being-set-for-vim-on-os-x#685112).